# Type or namespace could not be found (Web Site)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web, namespaces

I created an ASP.NET Web App project and it builds and works correctly now.  However, I am trying to add this project to my website.  So what I've done is I create a new Web Site from VS and then I added all of the .CS files from my Web App project to this Web Site.

Even though the Web App project builds successfully, when I use this same code in my Web Site and I build it, I get the error:

> The type or namespacae name
>   'ADONET_namespace' could not be found
>   (are you missing a user directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

Here is the top part of my master.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace AddFileToSQL
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
```

And the top of my ADONET_methods.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;

namespace ADONET_namespace
{
    public class ADONET_methods : System.Web.UI.WebControls
    {
```

Finally the top of my child class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using ADONET_namespace;

namespace AddFileToSQL
{
    public partial class DataMatch : _Default
    {
```

In this child class file, there is a squiggly line under ADONET_namespace and hovering over it returns the error specified above.  I have this ADONET_methods.cs file stored in same file structure format on this Web Site as I do on my Web App project.  So if it builds successfully in that project, why not in this Web Site?

I have searched Stack Overflow for similar questions and I found one question which was asking the same thing as me, but I tried all of the solutions listed there.  I also googled this problem and tried all of the suggestions, but none of them worked either.  And I have added this ADONET_methods.cs file to different locations within this Web Site to test out if it was being found or not, like under App_Data folder, References folder, and also in the same level as the other .CS files (like it is in the Web App project).

What else can I try?  This code is written in C# by the way in VS 2008, running on an XP Pro with IIS6 Manager.

Comment: Let's first work out what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you building a web site and trying to include a class library, or did you build a web app project and would like to convert it to a web site project?  Basically, what is your ultimate goal?

Also, the class named ADONET_namespace is the same name as the namespace itself, which should be changed to something different (the class).

Comment: I built a web app project and am trying to convert this to a web site project.  My ultimate goal is to store my web app/web site project on my default web site from IIS6.  But I was having difficulties with this, like username/password issues (see my other questions).  
So I reviewed one of my ASP.NET books and it suggested creating a web site project cause this makes u specify a URL for the location prior to creating it.  
That was a good catch about the ADONET_namespace class.  I changed it to ADONET_methods class as it was originally but I still get the same error.

Comment: BTW, I edited that one line above containing the class name.

Answer (score 4):

For each code -- example: .cs -- file in the App_Code folder, ensure that the Build Action property is set to "Compile" and not "Content" or anything else.

Comment: +1, This was my problem when I moved files over from my Web Site project to a Web App project.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in your App_Code directory.

Comment: Yes, I already have this in my App_Code and References directory, as well as one copy at the same level as the other .CS files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is causing any issues, but do you want your **class** in the `ADONET_methods.cs` file to be named `ADONET_namespace`?  It seems odd to have both the class and the namespace with the same name.

Comment: It shouldn't cause any issues, but it isn't exactly best practice either ;)

Comment: Good catch guys, I originally did not have same name.  I edited my question to how it matches my code now.  Now, the class has a different name than the namespace.

Comment: Is there a "parent" namespace involved, such as the default namespace for the project that you need to include in the `using` statement on the `DataMatch` class, such as `using MyProject.ADONET_namespace;`?

Comment: No, there's no "parent" namespace involved.  I tried making it:
using AddFileToSQL.ADONET_namespace, but this caused same error message.  What about assembly reference?  What does that mean?  I included the ADONET_methods.CS file in the References folder.  Does this satisfy this requirement?

Comment: Maybe you could try looking at the class view of the project and see if that shows you exactly where the compiler is expecting to find the ADONET_namespace.  VS2008 menu -> View -> Class View.  That shows you the classes and namespace tree.